# Get variable from another table in a WHILE loop

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$id = $_SESSION['user_id'] ;
echo "<form method='post' action='#'>";
echo "</select>
<p>Which Hospital Would You Like to Submit To?</p>";
$queryitem  = "SELECT * FROM vendor_hospital WHERE vendor_hospital.user_id = '$id' AND vendor_hospital.approval_status = '1'" or die('MYSQL error: ' . mysql_error());
if ($result = mysql_query($queryitem)) {
    if ($success = mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo "<select name='hospital_name'>";
        echo "<option>-- Select A Facility --</option>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        echo "<option value='$row[manufacturer_id]'>$row[manufacturer_id]</option>";
        echo "</select><br><br>";
    } else {
        echo "No results found.";
    }
} else {
    echo "Failed to connect to database.";
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit' name='submit' class='button' /></form>";
?>
```

For some reason I'm stuck here. I'm just trying to get the manufacturer name to show in my options instead of the manufacturer_id. The manufacturer name is a foreign key in another table so I can't simply call `$row[manufacturer_id]` in my option tag. What should I do here? My only thought is to run a query inside the option tag for every manufacturer_id listed as a value but I'm sure that is overkill. Can someone point me in the right direction of a more elegant solution than that?

Comment: You should use a JOIN instead of a separate query.

Comment: geez, thanks. Thought it would be something easy. Thanks Brad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you are trying to do...but try this.

Replace this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
echo "<option value='$row[manufacturer_id]'>$row[manufacturer_id]</option>";
echo "</select><br><br>";
```

With this:

```
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<option value='".$row['manufacturer_id']."'>".$row['manufacturer_id']."</option>";
}
        echo "</select><br><br>";
```

Also be sure to double check and make sure that you are pulling from the right database, that it is populated, you are calling the right table names, etc...

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ernest. Brad hit the nail on the head. I just needed access to a column in a table that wasn't in my SELECT statement. A JOIN did the trick

Comment: Wow! It's been a while since I answered this.  But I'm glad you got it figured out :)